# Blue hue/tint in "white" margin of scanned docs or photos. Lubuntu 13.10 ,Epson V200 photo scanner

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, scanner, epson

I've had this scanner sitting around, and I decided to see if I could set it up on my old Compaq Presario V2000, running Lubuntu 13.10. The scanner is an Epson V200 perfection. 
For the drivers( my computer is 32bit), I went [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) and in this order, I downloaded and installed:

```
    1. `iscan-data_1.34.0-1_all.deb`

    2.iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb

    3.iscan-plugin-gt-f670_2.1.2-1_i386.deb
```

After that, the scanner worked in both simple scan and image scan. However, the white fields in pictures were now light blue(not solid though), and the lines of the pictures had a strange double effect in blue and red lines. Almost like you're looking at a 3d image, without the 3d glasses. I'm assuming it's a driver issue, and from the few old threads I've seen, there may not be a fix. I thought I'd try and post here for any ideas.

Below is actually one of the better results I've gotten from scanning. I just scanned a random text sheet(photos are a lot worse). As you can see, there is a weird blueish, splotchy haze and some of the text is "Psychedelic"

[image: example of results]

Comment: White balance, making white look blueish?

Comment: I updated, with an example. I can't find anything regarding white balance in either of the built-in scanner programs. I played around with some hue,gamma, contrast and lightening, but it's not an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

This is, almost certainly, a failing lamp. You are, maybe, in luck. Most of today's scanners use something called a Cold Cathode lamp. The older style scanners used a special lamp with a high CRI (Color Rendering Index) which uses a wider spectrum than your usual house lamps. As lamps with a high CRI are not generally replaced (disposable society and all that) there is not a very large market for them. You do see replaceable lamps but that is generally with the more expensive scanners, those used in a professional setting where they pay a great deal of money and often have a specialist company maintain their print rooms (which is often where the scanners are).

Now, this doesn't mean you're entirely out of options. You can do a few things to resolve this situation, maybe:

You can find a forum, if one exists, full of enthusiasts. I did not see one for your model. You may have better luck than I. One of them may be able to find a lamp or know where you can find one.

You can try the myriad online resources in hopes of finding a working model that matches your own and harvest the lamp from that one. It's not difficult to change your lamp and, believe it or not, this may actually be your least expensive and most viable solution. You do need to make sure that it is not a Cold Cathode first. (More on that below.)

Finally, you can call the manufacturer or use their online contacts and see if they will find, sell, and help you change the lamp. Having dealt with this company in the past, I wish you luck.

Now, assuming that Google is correct and you do, indeed, have the older style lamp (the newer lamps are not user-serviceable) then you can try [this site](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supAdvice.jsp?UseCookie=yes&type=highlights&noteoid=153590) to get the current contact information for user-serviceable parts replacements. They should be able to tell you if it is a Cold Cathode or a CRI lamp.

If they can give you the part number there's a very limited chance that a specialty lamp shop will carry this. As you have a consumer model, there doesn't seem to be a detailed technical spec chart online.

Sorry that this is, unlikely, an operating system issue and can't be fixed by tweaking and poking. To be honest, the lamps are expensive and it may be worth it to simply replace it with a newer model if you can't find a cadaver to strip for parts.

I've gone through this, albeit with a different model, myself and my scans looked a lot like the one you're sharing with us. I wish there were more to do but it's almost certainly a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd test the scanner in Windows to see if the drivers there have any better luck. It could be that if the scanner's been *"sitting around"* a long time maybe it's just getting old & dirty & no longer scans properly at all? Testing in windows would confirm if it's a driver issue, or a scanner issue.

If it does only work well in Windows, then trying to use it with WINE is a (remote?) possibility, or even running Windows in a VM (an old XP version with no networking may even be good enough) might work?

In the image it doesn't look a whole lot worse than other old scans on old scanners I've seen. I can see the text on the other side of the paper coming through (looks like that anyway).

And the red-blue-yellow separating looks similar to an inkjet printer out of alignment, maybe here the scanner is "slipping" or something and not reading correctly? If the separating were all over the image I'd more agree with a driver issue, but it being only in one little section I'm thinking hardware... maybe a good cleaning could help?